# "Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible": Recoding numeric variables

Tags: r, na, incompatibility, recode, .x

I have a numeric variable (V110) that takes on values between 1-4. As the numbers stand for higher (1) and lower (4) trust in the govt, I want to recode them, so that the highest value signifies the highest and the lowest value the lowest trust. Now I tried the following syntax:

```
wv6$n.V110 <- recode(wv6$V110, "1=4; 2=3; 3=2; 4=1")
```

But R keeps outputting an error message saying:

> Warning message: Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not
>   compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply
>   .default

I checked the individual answers i.e. values given and some of them say -2 (i.e. a value that doesn't belong to the section "1-4", could that be the problem? I tried to add both ".default=NA" or "else=NA" at the end of the syntax  but this doesn't make the error go away. Any help?

Comment: if your variable is `numeric`, why not `wv6$n.V110 <- 5 - wv6$V110` ?

Answer (score 5):

Might it be that you loaded the packages `car` and `dplyr`?

`recode` can be used by both package. That for you need to specify which package will apply when using `recode`.

In your case:

```
wv6$n.V110 <- car::recode(wv6$V110, "1=4; 2=3; 3=2; 4=1")
```

That worked out perfectly for me as car was masked by `dplyr`.